# How to plot a matrix as a 3D imshow plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to plot a 4x4 array as a 3D plot in matplotlib, but I'm facing issues with the plot_surface function. The resulting graph only displays a surface with a 3x3 color grid, instead of a 4x4 color grid. I suspect that plot_surface may not be the appropriate approach for visualizing the complete matrix. I would like to achieve a visualization similar to a "3D imshow", but I'm uncertain if this is possible in matplotlib.

I have included a minimal reproducible example below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.meshgrid(range(0, 4), range(0, 4))
z = -0.5 * x + 0.5 * y

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cstride=1, rstride=1, shade=False, cmap='plasma')
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z)
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there a way to modify this code to plot the complete 4x4 matrix as a 3D plot? Alternatively, is there an alternative approach in matplotlib that would allow me to visualize all the values in the surface plot? I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: You have 4 points on _x_, hence 3 columns, etc

Comment: How exactly do you want the plot to represent your data? Right now each corner of the surface plot represents exactly one point of your matrix. The squares in between consist of (infinite) pairs of xs and ys, all NOT beingt the pairs your matrix consists of. I could only imagine a plot where the center of each such square is at the matrix entrys. In that case you would need to calculate the corners aroud your data, but how do you determine the square's inclination? It would work for your example, since all points are on the same plane, but if they are part of a curved surface it becomes ugly.

Comment: @Flow I see, I was thinking of recalculating the values of x, y and z so that each square represented the value of the matrix. So I would have to recalculate the node values, but as you said, it would not be possible to calculate the inclination and give the effect of a curved surface, which is what I would like. So I believe that this representation that I want is not possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This answer creates a 3D barplot as an alternative method for representing your data. This will allow you to visualize the surface with each column representing a single z-value. It is also possible to view a flattened heat map of the array by rotating the figure to display the 'bottom'.

`NOTE:` I used a different, larger sample set in order to create the examples. This is just to show that the method works for more complex inputs.

#### Example Output

[image: Barplot of data]

This is a barplot of a larger sample set. You can clearly see the data being represented even though the 'surface' of the data is not flat.

[image: Bottom up view]

This is a bottom-up view of the figure. It represents a heatmap of your input data.

#### Code

```
from matplotlib import cbook
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Load and format data
dem = cbook.get_sample_data('jacksboro_fault_dem.npz', np_load=True)
z = dem['elevation']
nrows, ncols = z.shape
x = np.linspace(dem['xmin'], dem['xmax'], ncols)
y = np.linspace(dem['ymin'], dem['ymax'], nrows)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

region = np.s_[5:50, 5:50]
x, y, z = x[region].ravel(), y[region].ravel(), z[region].ravel()

# parameters for bar3d(...) func
bottom = np.full_like(z, np.min(z))
width = (np.max(x)-np.min(x))/np.sqrt(np.shape(x)[0])
depth = (np.max(y)-np.min(y))/np.sqrt(np.shape(y)[0])

# creating color_values for the figure
offset = z + np.abs(z.min())
fracs = offset.astype(float)/offset.max()
norm = colors.Normalize(fracs.min(), fracs.max())
color_values = cm.jet(norm(fracs.tolist()))

# Set up and display the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax.bar3d(x,y,bottom,width,depth,z, color=color_values, shade=True)

## Used to view the figure from the bottom
# ax.view_init(270, 0)

plt.show()
```

Does this help?

#### Documentation

[3D Bar Charts from Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/3d_bars.html)

[Another example using the sample data from Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/custom_shaded_3d_surface.html)

Comment: The solution is very interesting and useful. But in my case it would not be applicable, as I would like the graph to look like a smoothed surface and not several bars.